# Opening selected ArcMap document failed?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mxd

Has anyone come across this error when opening up a MXD file?

> Opening the selected ArcMap document failed.

[image]

ArcMap had frozen on me right before this, even though no processes were in the middle of running - clicking anywhere triggered no response other than that super annoying "ding!".  I was able to close the program by right clicking in the task bar and selecting close, at which point I was asked to save the results of the editing session I was in and also save the MXD file.  I did both.  And now it can't be opened up.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really are fairly stuck here. You may be able to recover your map document using the [MXD Doctor tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Using_the_MXD_Doctor_utility/000300000019000000/):

> MXD Doctor is a stand-alone application provided with ArcGIS:
>   *(Start>All Programs>ArcGIS>Desktop Tools>MXD Doctor)*  It provides
>   functionality to analyze broken .mxd files. Depending on the analysis,
>   entities contained in the broken .mxd file can be copied from the
>   broken file into a new or existing .mxd file.

Comment: This fixed whatever the problem was!  I actually didn't know that there was such a thing!

Answer (score 3):

You could try opening the mxd from WITHIN ArcMap vs using the mxd itself to launch ArcMap.

I've seen that before where an mxd won't open from double-clicking, but instead needs to be opened from within the program

Answer (score 2):

This issue happened to me this morning, and I solved it by going to Windows Explorer, right clicking on the MXD file, COPY, paste. Now you have the original and a new copy, and the copy opened just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the identical data frame error. MXD Dr did nothing. I had recently pulled in a shp file that had been edited in QGIS. The shp had loaded OK and I was able to pull data from it. But that SHP somehow caused an issue.

To fix my MXD, I renamed the folder where my data was located. When I tried to reopen my MXD, it loaded fine except all the links to the features had the red "!" beside them. I removed the offending shp file, resaved and closed the MXD. Re-renamed my data folder back to its original name and restarted ArcMap. The MXD and all its data loaded normally.